# user_path Not working in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby on rails application have two model User and Location

User model

```
belongs_to :location
```

Location model

```
has_many :users
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

This view in location show page

```
<% @location.users.each do |locuser| %>
   <%= link_to locuser.email, user_path %><br>      
<% end %>
```

**Error is Couldn't find User with 'id'**

This my Users Controller

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

I added `<%= link_to locuser.email, current_user %>`
 it also not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am considering you are not using devise routes. where no need to pass user object to routes. In your show action you do need id so I am passing user object for show path. If this is not the case run `rake routes | grep user` and paste log here

it should be `user_path(locuser)`

try change :

```
<% @location.users.each do |locuser| %>
   <%= link_to locuser.email, user_path(locuser) %><br>      
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% @location.users.each do |locuser| %>
   <%= link_to locuser.email, locuser %><br>      
<% end %>
```